# Testing for heterogeneity by a multi-level categorical variable in a cox regression

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am interested to know if there is heterogeneity in a multi-level categorical variable in a survival model. Does Cox make sense given the test of heterogeneity would assume proportional hazards - which is kind of what we are testing for?